# number of ways to put n balls in n-1 slots so that only 1 has 2 balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The problem says

> We have n balls and n slots. And asks for the probability that exactly the first slot has no balls and exactly one of them has 2 balls.

My attempt: There are $n^{n}$ total possible permutations so we will divide by that.

Now lets pick off one of the balls. $n$ choices there...
We are left with $n-1$ balls and same number of slots so $(n-1)!$ permutations there...
and finally we have $n-1$ choices of slots to put the ball we had initially picked off in. So the total probability is $(n)(n-1)(n-1)!/n^{n}.$

The answer in the book however also divides the numerator by $2$ and i can't quite see why. What is wrong in my thought process?
Thank you.

Comment: oh i think i see the problem:
say we have 5 balls, i could pick the option
1 2,3 4 if i had picked out ball number 3 originally, or i could have picked option 1 3,2 4 if i had picked out ball 2 originally, so for each one of these permutations there will be 2 options and thats why we divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

One of the $n-1$ slots will have two balls: It can be picked in $n-1$ ways. The two balls in that slot can be in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. The remaining $n-2$ balls can be placed in the remaining $n-2$ slots in $(n-2)!$ ways.

Altogether:
$$
(n-1)\times\binom{n}{2}\times (n-2)!\quad \text{ways}.
$$

Comment: i know this method, but these combinatorial problems often leave you wondering what was wrong with YOUR method. So i added a comment to my question, can you check if that is what was wrong please. Thanks.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, I came across this question and I think your answer is wrong. You implicitly assume that each of the remaining $(n-2)$ balls is put in his own slot. However, it does not violate the assumptions of the question if $3, 4, 5, ...n-2$ balls are put together in the same slot. So you also have to consider those possibilities in your solution. What do you think?